# How to remove previous fragment from back stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working with the fragments navigation and have a problem removing one from the back stack. Here're specifics:
I have 3 independent fragments (let's name them **A1, A2, and A3**) and each of them can navigate to **fragment B** using `findNavController().navigate()`, which after some actions navigates to **fragment C** using the same method.
What I need is when the *back arrow* is pressed I return to the **A-fragment**(which I started from) avoiding **fragment B**.
I've tried using `app:popUpTo`, and `popBackStack` but it hadn't worked. Also, I'm highly not recommended to use FragmentManager

Comment: You can use findNavController().popUp(2)

Comment: Have you followed the docs on `popUpTo`? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop You need to set `popUpTo` on the `action` that's navigating you from *B* to *C*, so that as part of that move, it pops some stuff off the backstack ready for when you hit the back button, so it'll go where you wanted to. And no you shouldn't be touching `FragmentManager`s if you're using the *Navigation* library, it'll interfere with that working properly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cactustictacs you saved me, while reading docs myself I didn't quite understood how popUpTo is working and where to put it, but after you comment and rereading docs i got the point and it worked. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
findNavController().popUp(2)
```